# How to supress the Servertime by ASP.NET API Response?

Tags: c#, date, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

Is there any way to send **no** Servertime in the Response to the client?
I found no way, so I want to ask here. Sorry when I overlook something.

I have an ASP.NET API with a ControllerBase-Class with a [HttpPost]-function and calling it by curl, the Servertime is shown 
| date:  Wed, 22 Jun 2022 13:19:43 GMT | 
as example.

Comment: is it ASP.NET Core Web API or ASP.NET framework ?

Comment: ASP.NET Core Web API

Comment: As far as i know, In ASP.NET Core web API it is not possible to remove the time from response. as it is added very late in response pipeline so even we can't use middleware to remove it. only possibility would be to ask dotnet guys to implement it similar to AddServerHeader property.